# How to use cartodb.js without storing sql in javascript

Tags: javascript, sql, carto, carto-js

Using cartodb.js, how can I change the layer definition without building the sql dynamically in javascript and passing it as a parameter.  Aside from revealing my table structure (not a huge deal at the moment, but it might be later on), it seems like a bit of a maintenance headache.

```
mylayer.set({
  sql: "select * from mytable WHERE somefield = 'x'"
});
```

I don't see (but could be missing) options within CartoDb itself.  Another option is I could set up a separate web server where I would send a request (e.g. `someotherserver.com/request?somefield=x`) which could then generate sql and then talk to CartoDB and return the results.  The problem with that approach is that calling `layer.set(...)` provides a good deal of additional functionality that I'm not sure my separate web server would be able to provide.

Does anyone have a good solution to this problem?

Answer (score 5):

If you want to have different visualisations but only modifying your query params, for instance because a filter changed and you want to change your where from `WHERE somefield = 'x'` to `WHERE somefield = 'y'`, probably you want to have a look at the [named maps + templates functionality provided by the Maps API](http://docs.cartodb.com/cartodb-platform/maps-api.html#named-maps-1). That allows you to create visualisations without exposing your queries/table structure but also allows you to change the queries dynamically.

First thing to do is create a named map with your API key, if you have a `template.json`:

```
{
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "name": "world_borders",
  "auth": {
    "method": "open"
  },
  "placeholders": {
    "color": {
      "type": "css_color",
      "default": "#FF6600"
    }
  },
  "layergroup": {
    "version": "1.0.1",
    "layers": [
      {
        "type": "cartodb",
        "options": {
          "cartocss_version": "2.3.0",
          "cartocss": "#layer { polygon-fill: <%= color %>; polygon-opacity: 1; line-color: #FFF; line-width: 1; line-opacity: 1; }",
          "sql": "select * from world_borders"
        }
      }
    ]
  }
}
```

The important part in the template is the `"placeholders"` and the `<%= color %>` part of the `"cartocss"`, that is what allows you to change colors later on. You can do the same with the query, check the documentation link I provided before.

You can do a POST request to the Maps API like in:

```
curl -X POST \
   -H "Content-Type: application/json" \
   -d @template.json \
   "https://${CDB_USERNAME}.cartodb.com/api/v1/map/named?api_key=${CDB_API_KEY}"
```

That will give you the name of your template, then you can use that name with cartodb.js to instantiate the layer and add it to your map:

```
cartodb.createLayer(map, {
    user_name: '${CDB_USERNAME}',
    type: 'namedmap',
    options: {
        named_map: {
            name: '${CDB_USERNAME}@world_borders',
            params: {
              "color": "#5CA2D1"
            }
        }
    }
})
.addTo(map)
```

**As you can see using the type "namedmap" you just have to use the name of the template/named map and you don't expose the queries in the JavaScript, not even the table name neither the structure.**

Later on you can modify the color param using the layer object like:

```
.done(function(layer) {
    // later on we change the color
    setTimeout(function() {
        layer.setParams({
            color: '#FF6600'
        });
    }, 5000);
});
```

You can check a working example in the following bl.ock.org: http://bl.ocks.org/rochoa/656f1eee8b3adddf3756

Answer (score 2):

I use squel.js to create SQL queries in javascript. It's pretty straightforward + lightweight to boot:

http://hiddentao.github.io/squel/